# Button IsEnabled Trigger does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, button, triggers, isenabled

I have a `Button` and its Style:

```
<Button Name="MyBtn" Style="{StaticResource ButtonEnabledStyle}"
        IsEnabled="False" Opacity="1" />

<Style x:Key="ButtonEnabledStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.1" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But when I enable the Button (`MyBtn.IsEnabled = true`) it does not change its Opacity. Why? How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: At which point are you calling MyBtn.IsEnabled = true? Maybe before style is initialized?

Comment: @Vale no, i call when i click in another button, the controls have already been Loaded.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A local value set on the element (`Opacity="1"` in your code) will always take precedence over a style or style trigger value. Please have a look at [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

An easy fix is to set the default value on the style instead:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonEnabledStyle" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0" />
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" >
      <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.1" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```